# Using Vaadin widgets in a GWT application

Tags: gwt, vaadin

Is it possible to use widgets from the Vaadin-framework from within a GWT application?

I know it works the other way round, which is also documented in the Vaadin docs. But I didn't find a descrption for integrating Vaadin widgets in an ordinary GWT application.

Comment: Answers to this question need to be updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately no, at least not out-of-the-box. Vaadin uses a server-side architecture, which means that all the widgets' states are stored on the server and not in the browser's memory, hence making the widgets dependent on the server-side. The communication between a widget's client-side and server-side is implemented deep in the core of Vaadin, so I think it would require quite a lot of work to get the widgets to work in a pure GWT environment.

Comment: I think that this needs to be updated now. I am not completely sure, but things may have changed.